# How does zookeeper handle multiple watches to a same zkPath from a same Watcher?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

i wanted to understand how would zookeeper handle multiple watches 
i.e assume there is watcher **MyWatcher** and a zkPath **myZkPath**, here whenever i call *exists()* with **MyWatcher** it keeps adding watches to **myZkPath**. 
     My question here is how are these list of watches for a same zkPath handled from a same zk session when there is only one notification in future? Will there be only one notification for the list of same watches or something else is gonna happen?